# binding dropdown selected value

Tags: microsoft-metro

How to bind selected value of dropdown in metro style app using `data-win-bind`

```
 <select class="win-interactive itemCount" data-win-bind="itemKey: key; selected: quantity; selectedValue: quantity; value: quantity;" >
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: Are you trying to bind setting the value on the select element, or are you expecting it to be a two way binding? (e.g. when the user changes their value, it sets back on your data object?)

Comment: it is only one way. binding value on the select element.

Answer (score 2):

Use repeater on the select tag and bind it to list of values and content:

```
<select id="repeater" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater">
    <option data-win-bind="value: Val; textContent: Content"></option>
</select>
```